# Requirements for JSON Parser

Tags: delphi, json, delphi-2009

I'm thinking about implementing JSON parser for Delphi.
What should a good JSON parser do? Any ideas for requirements?
I believe it should at least output and process JSON...
Looking at XML parsers, should it be more DOM or SAX-like?

Answer (score 4):

I think [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) does a pretty bang up job.

- JsonReader and JsonWriter for low
  level work of parsing and outputting JSON
- JsonSerializer for converting objects to and from JSON
- JObject, JArray and JValue classes for working
  with JSON in an object model

Note I may be a bit bias since I wrote it :)

Comment: Absolutely -- separation between streaming/incremental parser/generator, and higher-level full in-memory constructs is a must in my opinion.

Comment: This is the [DBXJSON](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBXJSON) unit approach.

Answer (score 3):

A good floor would be all the functionality provided by the following 3 (taken from [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/)): [uJson](http://sourceforge.net/projects/is-webstart/), [JSON Toolkit](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=6), and [lkjson](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lkjson).

Answer (score 2):

I've used the JSON toolkit in several projects, with great success. The only thing I've modified at some point was the way it formats resulting JSON, but it's a matter of personal taste.

It's free, fairly clean, and easy to use. No need to install packages; just have a .pas file somewhere in your path. Just check **test_usage.dpr** below for some simple examples on how to use it. It doesn't get much easier than that.

I wouldn't waste my time trying to implement yet another JSON parser, unless you want to do it for educational purposes, in which case you should carefully study existing implementations anyway.

JSON Toolkit home:
http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=6

```
program test_usage;
{$IFDEF FPC}
  {$MODE OBJFPC}{$H+}
{$ELSE}
  {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$ENDIF}

uses
  SysUtils,
  superobject;

var
  my_string, my_int, my_object, my_array: ISuperObject;
  new_obj: ISuperObject;
  j: integer;
  ite: TSuperObjectIter;

begin
  try
    my_string := TSuperObject.Create(#9);
    writeln('my_string=', my_string.AsString);
    writeln('my_string.AsJSon=', my_string.AsJSon);

    my_string := TSuperObject.Create('foo');
    writeln('my_string=', my_string.AsString);
    writeln('my_string.AsJson=', my_string.AsJson);

    my_int := TSuperObject.Create(9);
    writeln('my_int=', my_int.AsInteger);
    writeln('my_int.AsJson=', my_int.AsJson);

    my_array := TSuperObject.Create(stArray);
    my_array.I[''] := 1; // append
    my_array.I[''] := 2; // append
    my_array.I[''] := 3; // append
    my_array.I['4'] := 5;
    writeln('my_array=');
    with my_array.AsArray do
    for j := 0 to Length - 1 do
      if O[j] = nil then
        writeln(#9'[', j,']=', 'null') else
        writeln(#9'[', j,']=', O[j].AsJson);
    writeln('my_array.AsJson=', my_array.AsJson);

    my_object := TSuperObject.Create(stObject);
    my_object.I['abc'] := 12;
   // my_object.S['path.to.foo[5]'] := 'bar';
    my_object.B['bool0'] := false;
    my_object.B['bool1'] := true;
    my_object.S['baz'] := 'bang';
    my_object.S['baz'] := 'fark';
    my_object.AsObject.Delete('baz');
    my_object['arr'] := my_array;
    writeln('my_object=');
    if ObjectFindFirst(my_object, ite) then
    repeat
      writeln(#9,ite.key,': ', ite.val.AsJson);
    until not ObjectFindNext(ite);
    ObjectFindClose(ite);
    writeln('my_object.AsJson=', my_object.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('"003"');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('/* hello */"foo"');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('// hello'#10'"foo"');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('"\u0041\u0042\u0043"');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('null');
    if new_obj = nil then
      writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', 'null');

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('true');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('12');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('12.3');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('["\n"]');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('["\nabc\n"]');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('[null]');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('[]');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('["abc",null,"def",12]');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('{}');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('{ "foo": "bar" }');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('{ "foo": "bar", "baz": null, "bool0": true }');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('{ "foo": [null, "foo"] }');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('{ "abc": 12, "foo": "bar", "bool0": false, "bool1": true, "arr": [ 1, 2, 3, null, 5 ] }');
    writeln('new_obj.AsJson=', new_obj.AsJson);

    new_obj := TSuperObject.Parse('{ foo }');
    if (new_obj = nil) then
      writeln('got error as expected');

    my_string := nil;
    my_int := nil;
    my_object := nil;
    my_array := nil;
    new_obj := nil;


    writeln(#10'press enter ...');
    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      writeln(E.Message)
  end;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented a pull-style parser in Java, which I find very nice to use.  It parses strictly conforming JSON, with some relaxations accepted (primarily for my specific purposes).  It is published and detailed [on my website](http://www.softwaremonkey.org/Code/).  Also published is an additional method which illustrates a document load using the parser - so you can use it either stream-oriented or document oriented.

I highly recommend pull style parsng (I have an XML parser which is pull, also).

Comment: AFAIK what you call a pull-style parser is a SAX family one, i.e. launching callbacks for each JSON item. It's fast, but for instance the http://vtd-xml.sf.net approach is more powerful, since it won't need to parse the JSON/XML content each time you want to access a node, by maintaining a "directory" in memory or file.

Comment: @A.Bouchez: No, it's not.  It's an *event* style parser, but instead of invoking a *parse* function that pushes events by invoking listeners, you invoke a *nextEvent* function that pulls the next event from the stream.  The difference is subtle, but I've used both and very much prefer a pull-parser.

Comment: @A.Bouchez: BTW, the acronym SAX stands for Simple API for XML, though many people associate SAX with event-based parsing, since that's what it is, an event-pushing API, though specifically for XML.

Comment: @SM Thanks for info. AFAIK, what you call a *pulled event* is a *reversed callback*. How the parsing is made is a matter of taste. In fact, my Delphi JSON parser is pull-based, if I follow your terminology. So I agree with you that I prefer this approach than a callback. But my remark about the fact that it will induce "to parse the whole JSON/XML content each time you access a node" is still true. The vtd-xml approach, creating a "directory" pointing to the JSON/XML data makes it a one time parsing. During the pulling, my parser will unescape the content in place and make such a "directory".

Comment: @A.Bouchez: What you describe is a form of document loading, very easily implemented as a layer on top of an event parser.  Either that or you completely misunderstand how an event parser works - it reads/parses only as much of the document as is required to get the next event, eventually processing the whole document one event at a time.

Comment: @SM 1. Read the question: it was about SAX and DOM, not only the parser part. 2. See my answer below, and the code of my JSON parser, and you'll see that I understood how an event parser works, since I coded one. Please look at the code before making assumptions. I read yours. 3. I suspect you didn't get the [vtd-xml approach](http://vtd-xml.sf.net) I talked about, and implemented over an pull-style parser, to build IMHO the fastest JSON parser in Delphi. Faster than your Java version, in all cases.

Comment: @A.Bouchez: I apologize if I sounded condescending in my comment; such was not my intent, though re-reading the comment I can see how one might take it that way - I did not intend on getting into a parser pissing contest.  I *do* "get" the VTD approach (in fact I have used just such an approach in other areas) and I think it's a rather ingenious alternative to DOM when you need a structured document in memory.  My use of JSON and XML has typically been to load and either process it inline or transform it on the fly to a radically different format, for  which an event based parser is ideal.

Answer (score 2):

When it deals with parsing some (textual) content, two directions are usually envisaged. In the XML world, you have usually to make a choice between:

- A DOM parser, which creates an in-memory tree structure of objects mapping the XML nodes;
- A SAX parser, which reads the XML content, then call pre-defined events for each XML content element.

In fact, DOM parsers use internally a SAX parser to read the XML content. Therefore, with the overhead of object creation and their property initialization, DOM parsers are typically three to five times slower than SAX. But, DOM parsers are much more powerful for handling the data: as soon as it's mapped in native objects, code can access with no time to any given node, whereas a SAX-based access will have to read again the whole XML content.

Most JSON parser available in Delphi use a DOM-like approach. For instance, the [DBXJSON](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBXJSON) unit included since Delphi 2010 or the [SuperObject](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=6) or [DWS](http://delphitools.info/?s=json) libraries create a class instance mapping each JSON node.

In a [JSON-based Client-Server ORM](http://blog.synopse.info/category/Open-Source-Projects/SQLite3-Framework) like ours, profiling shows that a lot of time is spent in JSON parsing, on both Client and Server side (on the Server, we convert JSON content into SQL on the fly). Therefore, we tried to optimize this part of the library.

In order to achieve best speed, we try to use a mixed approach:

- All the necessary conversion (e.g. un-escape text) is made in-memory, from and within the JSON buffer, to avoid memory allocation;
- The parser returns pointers to the converted elements (just like the [vtd-xml library](http://vtd-xml.sf.net/)).

The resulting speed is amazing, for both small and very large JSON content buffer.

In order to produce JSON, we wrote also some [fast JSON serialization functions](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/02/23/Fast-JSON-%28un%29serialization), from any object content.

For details and code source, see [this Blog's entry](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/06/02/Fast-JSON-parsing).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with James; there are 3 sensible ways to work with Json: as a stream of events/tokens; as a tree (like XML DOM), or by binding to/from "native" objects.
The package I am familiar with is Jackson (http://jackson.codehaus.org), and it also supports these 3 methods, similar to how (I assume) Json.NET does.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the nice thing about JSON is that it uses a fairly simple grammar and writing a parser for it is fairly simple.  "forgetting" all of the other implementations, but using Delphi I would start with the TParser class in the classes unit for a jumpstart.  Create separate methods to handle each element (some are already done in TParser, which is why I suggested starting from there).

Now, what to do with what you have parsed.  There is where the fun comes in.  If you mimic the interfaces and implementation of the TXmlDocument, then conversion to/from XML/JSON is  somewhat trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Jettison (http://jettison.codehaus.org/) is a popular JSON [StAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX) (Streaming API for XML) implementation, written in Java.

> Jettison is a collection of Java APIs
>   (like STaX and DOM) which read and
>   write JSON. This allows nearly
>   transparent enablement of JSON based
>   web services in services frameworks
>   like CXF or XML serialization
>   frameworks like XStream.